# Entity Framework 4.1 Performance in Cloud based SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I developed the Windows Application using Entity Framework 4.0  with SQL Server. In  development the SQL Server has been installed in local machine it self. While moving production my client wants to deploy the SQL Server in remote location, the insert/update operation is taking bit more time in Remote Server but it executes very fast if it is local server.

Please guide me how to improve the performance?

Comment: First, this is impossible to answer without any knowledge of the involved queries, traffic volume and bandwidth. Second, you should probably have kept this in mind during development or preach to the client about changing non-functional requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be caused by network problems or something with the SQL Server, to rule out either the SQL Server, you can use the Profiler and look at the times and others.

Regards